# How to import grid.js html function for using formatter in Vue

Tags: vue.js, gridjs

I am using the gridjs-vue wrapper to use grid.js with Vue. I'd like to use the formatter feature of gridjs, but it requires the html function. How do I import the html function into my component? If I try to import it from gridjs-vue, it says that html is not found in gridjs-vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this.$gridjs.html(...)`. Example:

```
this.cols = [
  {
    name: 'Model',
    formatter: cell => this.$gridjs.html(`<b>${cell}</b>`)
  },
  { ... },
  { ... }
]
```

See https://github.com/grid-js/gridjs-vue#gridjshtml